# Are there any principal Upanishads that don't mention the caste system?

Tags: upanishads, caste-system

Among Isha, Kena and Katha, Prashna, Mundaka, Mandukya, Tattiriya, Aitareya, Chhandogya and Brihadaranyaka upanishads, which, if any, don't mention the caste system at all?.

Comment: By caste do you mean varna? 'Caste' as used in the the Upanishads does not refer to the rigid crystalized version as imagined by most people today.